# Understanding an excerpt from a news article

Tags: comprehension

Please explain to me what the underlined parts mean

Clearly, in the post-Greenspan age, a central banker does not have the defences available to the brainy professor to ***blink his way out of misconstrued***, if not misconstructed, sentences. In fact, ***no one within coughing distance of a political stage does.*** Ask Gloria Steinem, who worried that young American women were missing the ***feminist logic of supporting Hillary Clinton in her quest for the Democratic nomination, as the “boys” were with rival Bernie Sanders.***

Please explain to me what

a) to blink his way out of misconstrued sentences means

b) no one within coughing distance of political stage means

c) feminist logic of supporting Hillary Clinton in her quest for the Democratic nomination, as the “boys” were with rival Bernie Sanders means

This is an excerpt from [an article in the Hindu](http://www.thehindu.com/opinion/editorial/editorial-of-umbrage-and-exception/article8520215.ece) so please help me understand it.

Comment: I think this is too many questions in one. Generally, you should limit questions to one area of concern rather than picking out every part of a paragraph that you don't understand. It will be much more difficult for a single person to answer this in a single answer with so many different questions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is cross-posted on another site: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/321793/

Answer (score 1):

I take it that this is the article: http://www.thehindu.com/opinion/editorial/editorial-of-umbrage-and-exception/article8520215.ece

"To blink your way out of something" means that getting out of that situation is as easy as blinking.

"Coughing distance of a political stage" means that someone is so close so someone in politics that if the politician coughed, the person would feel the effect.

The feminist logic sentence draws a comparison between how, to some, voting for Hillary is a feminist action, whereas some consider voting for Bernie as trying to keep the men in power.